# Grep to filter and show only the beginning of a line

Tags: text-processing, grep

(using MacOSX and may convert this to a perl script).
I'm fairly new to Linux/Unix commands, and my Google search has been unsuccessful.

I am creating a script to make it fast to search for a record of someone's training. The way I'm doing this is listing the individual's training records in one line (perhaps there's a better way?). When I use Grep to search for a specific name, position trained in, or date, it shows the entire line. I want to grep search for a specific string and show only the beginning of the line, IE: first 2 words (First name / last name.).

The Training.txt file looks similar to this:

> Ivie, Shawn Cashier 5/24/2016 Storeroom 12/2/2016 Service-Desk 11/31/2016
>
> Allen, Adam Cashier 5/10/2016 Storeroom 12/13/2016
>
> Martinez, Jessica Cashier 5/20/2017 Storeroom 10/29/2016 Supervisor 1/23/2016

The command I use now is:
`grep "Cashier" Training.txt`

which returns all 3 records, the entire line contents of all records.

I've tried:
`grep -E -o ".{0,0}Cashier.{0,5}" Training.txt`

which returns (in this example, all 3 records) but showing zero characters before "Cashier" and 5 after.

`Cashier 5/10`

How can I incorporate a grep (or perhaps a Perl command) to search for say, "Supervisor" and only show the first 2 words (names)?
Secondary: any ideas that may make this type of process easier? (Spreadsheet is just not useful in this case).

Answer (score 2):

This is perfect for `awk`:

```
awk '/Supervisor/ { print $1, $2 }' /path/to/inputfile
```

You can even restrict the search to the third field so that you don't get a false positive for someone named "Supervisor Bob":

```
awk '$3 ~ /Supervisor/ { print $1, $2 }' /path/to/inputfile
```

Comment: However, it would still fail for `de la Vallée Poussin, Charles-Jean Étienne Gustave Nicolas Le Vieux Supervisor`, or even for `Fotherington Thomas, Basil Cashier`.  Technically, dealing with names is a problem that is still open to this day.

Comment: True, but that's what you get for using both spaces and commas as field delimiters.  GIGO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` with the `Perl` mode on:

```
grep -oP '^(\S+,?\s+){2}(?=Cashier\s)'
```

### Results

```
Ivie, Shawn
Allen, Adam
Martinez, Jessica
```

### Working

- In Perl mode, grep is looking for two fields (\S+) from the beginning of line.
- And standing at the end of the whitespace of the 2nd field, if we are able to see a Cashier followed by a whitespace, we've found our match. Since, the Cashier string is as a lookaround, it won't be included in the match.

Comment: Trying your syntax, it's not working...missing something?

Comment: @Ivus MacOS X `grep` is not GNU. In that case, try using `ggrep`.